# What is the meaning of True in my result?

Tags: summation

When I do the sum

```
Sum[(a + (b + π n)^2)^(-1), {n, -∞, ∞}]
```

the result reads

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\coth \left(\sqrt{a}+i b\right)+\coth \left(\sqrt{a}-i b\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}} & \arg \left(\sqrt{a}-i b\right)\geq -\frac{\pi }{2}\land \arg \left(\sqrt{a}-i b\right)\leq \frac{\pi }{2} \\
 \frac{\coth \left(\sqrt{a}+i b\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}}+\frac{\coth \left(\sqrt{a}-i b\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
$$

What is the meaning of `True` in the second result?

If I get rid of $\pi$, the result is simply:

$$ \frac{-\pi  \cot \left(\pi  \sqrt{-a}+\pi  b\right)-\pi  \cot \left(\pi  \sqrt{-a}-\pi  b\right)}{2 \sqrt{-a}}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `Piecewise`.  It is like the `cases` environment in $\LaTeX$. In native math, one would use "else" instead of `True`.

By the way, version 12 returns

$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{\coth \left(\sqrt{a}-i b\right)+\coth \left(\sqrt{a}+i
   b\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}} & \arg \left(b+i \sqrt{a}\right)\geq 0 \\
 \frac{\coth \left(\sqrt{a}-i b\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}}+\frac{\coth
   \left(\sqrt{a}+i b\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} &
   \text{True}
\end{cases}$$

to be interpreted as

$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{\coth \left(\sqrt{a}-i b\right)+\coth \left(\sqrt{a}+i
   b\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}} & \arg \left(b+i \sqrt{a}\right)\geq 0 \\
 \frac{\coth \left(\sqrt{a}-i b\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}}+\frac{\coth
   \left(\sqrt{a}+i b\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} &
   \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ok, so it really simply means "otherwise" or "else" or "in all other cases"?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.